# Export Cadence Virtuoso Schematic to tikz

Tags: cadence, schematic, virtuoso

To export the layout to tikz, there's this great tool available: https://github.com/electronics-and-drives/ml2tikz

I thought there was a similar tool to export the schematic to tikz but I can't find it anymore.

Does someone remember where the tool is available to download and can provide a link or the relevant SKILL file? Or how do you get your schematics into a nice tikz plot?